# 3-Tier Architecture Data Access

Tags: database, web-services, n-tier-architecture, 3-tier

I am looking into developing a Social Network application for an Android device, and I will be using a RESTful web service that sits in the logic layer of an n-tier architecture.

Now I am getting a bit confused by the data layer and the logic layer. I see rules for the logic layer that say "Should not contain presentation or data access code" I get the presentation code part, but surely, if my web service was PHP, MySQL and Apache for example I would have to have something like

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT entry, name, level, description FROM
users ORDER BY name") or die(mysql_error());
```

(Ignore the fact this doesnt use mysqli)
Does this not belong in the business logic, and should there be a second web service on the machine that contains the database that would run this code based on information from the logic tier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In N-Tier applications, it is a good idea to separate your middle tier from your from the details or inner working of your data repository(s). In some projects this can be overkill.

This abstraction allows you to switch out RDMS or connect to multiple RDMS's without rewriting the business layer logic. Your code will also benefit from the modularity.

One way to achieve this is to encapsulate all your database tables with CRUD's (ORM mappers make this easy). In a since, these classes would become your data layer.

For example, At the highest level of your data layer, you might have a function that returns a list of users by userid, here user is a defined class that has matching properties to your data fields. So instead of returning some system data table object you are returning a list of your defined user objects.

Next, in your business layer, you plug into or are giving a data access class that you can get a list of users from (see dependency injection). You do not need to know, nor do you care, where the data came from. The list of users could have come from MySQL, a flat file, or a remote web service. This is why separation can be a good thing.

Some of the drawbacks to this approach would be having to rely on a third party ORM mappers (they make development faster), the need for translation classes for cross boundary communication, more planning involved for even the smallest of tweaks. However, the last point is less likely if you have CRUDS for every entity. The tweaks would only be needs when you change the attributes of the underlying data.

Edit: I forgot to mention that the Get/Update/Insert/Delete functions of your user repository would normally be accessible via an api tucked into a remote web service or something similar.

Comment: When using ORM Do you still use JSON to expose the data to the presentation tier? And the ORM just saves having to write the SQL query?

Comment: A Restful Api can return JSON results and most commonly do.

Comment: So you pull the Objects out of the database, and store them as objects of PHP classes, then convert the object to a JSON String?

Comment: That would be something you develop along side your web application. If you want to create a Restful Api for your application then you need to think hard about how you want to organize your data access and create an api and expose your endpoint. Your client application would use that api and render output to the user. If your API returns json that is up to you, however, once you decide on the semantics you should not change. You can also consider multiple output types. With routing you can use semantics similar to www.apiserver/myapp/<json|xml|pox>/users/1565

Comment: You serialize the php class to json and return this to the client. The client will need to know the attributes of the json object returned. You should look for php classes or functions to serialize an object or list of objects to json. I am sure there are tons of references.

Answer (score 0):

Your data access layer contains queries which extract data out of a data source. These queries usually sit behind a repository interface of some sort which allows other layers to communicate with the data access layer in a loosely-coupled fashion.

Your logical (aka business) layer contains workflows necessary to complete operations called upon by the presentation layer. In a tiered architecture, this layer should not contain raw data access queries, but it should instead use data access layer to query data via repository interface i mentioned above. I think this is what that rule is trying to say.